# Column names showing up different with head(df) and colnames(df)

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I want the column names to show up as what is under colnames, not head(tray).  Why are they showing up differently?  When I do:

```
colnames(tray)[17] <- "linearcorrect"
```

It changes the colnames, but not in the head(tray)

```
head(tray)
Date Row Identifier.1     Identifier.2 Amount Ampl..28 d.15N.14N Ampl..44 d.13C.12C Area.All.N Area.All.C
1 07/08/21  10 20210064.211         BB102382  5.220     2318     0.472     4794   -26.009     56.651    142.873
2 07/08/21  11 20210064.212         BB102383  5.018     2196     0.369     4662   -25.907     53.203    136.828
3 07/08/21  12 20210064.212 Replicate of A11  5.105     2318     0.372     4800   -25.915     54.442    139.648
4 07/08/21  13 20210064.213         BB102384  5.036     2358     0.255     4609   -26.763     55.389    129.823
5 07/08/21  14 20210064.214         BB102385  5.149     2481     0.324     4827   -26.892     56.956    139.306
6 07/08/21  15 20210064.215         BB102386  5.070     2401     0.109     4976   -26.378     55.618    145.311
  Percent.N Percent.C    C.N d.15N.14N Corr..d.13C d.15N.14N d.13C.12C Comment
1     1.264    19.406 15.353 -10.76307          NA -10.76307 -29.15730    <NA>
2     1.236    19.350 15.655 -10.13976          NA -10.13976 -29.04758    <NA>
3     1.234    19.393 15.716 -10.39775          NA -10.39775 -29.05918    <NA>
4     1.271    18.288 14.389 -10.71424          NA -10.71424 -29.89462    <NA>
5     1.282    19.188 14.967 -10.97532          NA -10.97532 -30.03574    <NA>
6     1.282    20.316 15.847 -10.90847          NA -10.90847 -29.52942    <NA>

colnames(tray)
[1] "Date"           "Row"            "Identifier.1"   "Identifier.2"   "Amount"         "Ampl..28"      
 [7] "d.15N.14N"      "Ampl..44"       "d.13C.12C"      "Area.All.N"     "Area.All.C"     "Percent.N"     
[13] "Percent.C"      "C.N"            "Corr..d.15N"    "Corr..d.13C"    "linearcorrect"  "linearcorrd13C"
[19] "Comment"
```

Comment: Can you please share the whole code of your renaming, e.g. column 18 also differs from the original tray data compared to the ony you retrieve by `colnames(tray)`. SO maybe some other steps in between cause this behaviour. Ideally, please also share an example of your data: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OK, I think I sort of figured out why this is happening.  The column class is data.frame.  Why is it adding a data.frame when I use the mutate() function?

Comment: @deschen OK.  Sorry about that I'm new to this.

Comment: Again, it's difficult to answer your question without knowing your code and the data. So if you could share (see link above) the chances of getting an answer will increase a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else with this problem, I used [[]] instead of [] around the variables I was calling into the calculation for linearcorrect column and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Andy Noakes, adding double brackets resolves this issue. Short code example:

```
for (i in 1:length(moult.date.list.spring)) {
  
  tmp.winter.end <- extract(winter.end[[i]], camera.spatial.spring)
  moult.date.list.spring[[i]]$winter.end <- tmp.winter.end[[2]] # Double brackets here

}
```